# Theorems relating compositions of functions and density

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, density-function

The stone-weirstrass theorem gives conditions for a suitable set to be dense in $C(X;\mathbb{R})$ assuming linear closure...
Are there any results about density of sets of functions closed under composition?

Comment: You mean in $C(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ cause otherwise closure under composition doesn't make sense. And what do you mean by "the theorem gives conditions"? As far as I know it simply states that polynomials are dense among continuous functions.

Comment: Sure $C(X;R)$ of C(R;R)$...basically I'm looking for a composition related analogue of the Stone-Weirstrass theorem (which is R-vectors spaced in nature).